# How to send a message with ping?

Tags: ping, icmp

The Ping command uses an ICMP request as far as I know

So is it possible to send a short text with the ping command right from commandline?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about `ping -p pattern`? Keep in mind that not all of versions of `ping` support `-p` option.

> You may specify up to 16 ''pad'' bytes to fill out the packet you
>   send. This is useful for diagnosing data-dependent problems in a
>   network. For example, -p ff will cause the sent packet to be filled
>   with all ones.

E.g. `ping -p 486920686572652e www.example.com`, *where 486920686572652e = Hi here.*

Comment: I saw the text decoded in wireshark on my other pc, so it works

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys, subprocess
text = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
if len(text)>16:
    print("Text too long!")
    exit()
enctext = r''.join( hex(ord(c)).split("x")[1] for c in text )
subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-p", enctext, "-c", "1", target])
```

Maybe this piece of code is helpful for somebody